# Find the actual height and width of element from rotated element

Tags: javascript, math, css-transforms, trigonometry

I have formula to get the rotated rectangle height and width as follows

```
radians = (Math.PI / 180) * degree;
x = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians)) * h + Math.abs(Math.cos(radians)) * w;
y = w * Math.abs(Math.sin(radians))  +  h * Math.abs(Math.cos(radians));
```

so the x, y values are new height and width after rotation.

Example The rectangle is rotated into 15 degrees and height 74 and width 110 are the values after rotation, I would like to find out the origin height (50) and width (100) of rectangle from those transformed values, I need to find out this through formula like above, so I can substitute with different values. [Sample Image of rotated rectangle](https://www.1800thesign.com/sample.jpg)

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to find and why what you have doesn't work

Comment: I was tried to reverse this formula to get the old height and width before rotation, but unsuccessful, so trying here

Comment: What is a rectangle with a 45° angle? Did you mean a triangle? In which case it's a degenerate triangle with height 0.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca
here is the link to the picture of rotated rectangle  (https://www.1800thesign.com/sample.jpg)

Comment: Ooops, I missed the word "rotated" in your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let denote

```
s = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians))
```

and similar for `c=cosine`. Then you have equation system

```
x = s * h + c * w
y = c * h + s * w
```

Multiply the first by c, the second by s

```
c * x = c * s * h + c * c * w
s * y = s * c * h + s * s * w
```

and subtract equations to get w

```
w * (c * c - s * s) = c * x - s * y
w = (c * x - s * y) / (c * c - s * s)
```

Do similar procedure for h (or express h with substitution of w in the first equation)

Note that 45/135/225/315 degrees produce **degenerate case**: denominator is zero, it is impossible to get true result - this is fundamental limitation, we can inscribe infinite number of rectangles with angle 45 into a square (x=y here)

```
w = ((c * rot_w) - (s * rot_h)) / (c * c - s * s);
h = ((c * rot_h) - (s * rot_w)) / (c * c - s * s);
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution. it doesn't give correct output, it should be 100, (https://jsfiddle.net/9yw7krxh/) refer the link. correct me If I missed anything

Comment: Remove double multiplication of x and y by coefficients and use angle say 30 [edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmexu6q4/). I added info

Comment: thank you, let's disregard those degrees, the formula works good but not the way I want. I want to get origin height and width of rectangle, 110 and 74 are height and width of rectangle values when rotating into 15 degrees, and the origin height and width of  rectangle are 50 height and 100 width. obviously I want to get these values 50, 100 as output when I substitute 110, 74 and 15 degree in the code.

Comment: When you apply x=110, y=74 and angle 15, you will get 100/50 https://jsfiddle.net/mpa86eqL/

Comment: I appreciate your patience, let's assume I do not know h=? and w=?, all I have 110, 74 and degree 15 and want to find h (50) =? and w (100) = ?. I do not know how else to explain. but you are awesome . Hope you can get through my mind to figure out what I am looking. Hope it could be my last try.